# Approximate string matching in php

Tags: php, preg-match-all, string-comparison

suppose I need to compare two variables

```
$team="Benfica(U23):Vitoria Guimaraes(U23)";
```

and

```
$team2="Benfica U23:Vitoria Guimaraes U23";
```

For my purpouse , $team and $team2 should match ,indeed they are the same fixture, only change U23 with (U23).

However preg_match is not so smart like a human, so if I use

```
if (preg_match("/$team/",$team2)) {
echo "they match";
}
```

they do not match, of course. How can I do an approximate preg_match
so that  $team and $team2 should be considered the same (very similar) by the preg_match check ?
For example in the preg_match above there are 4 chars errors due to the brackets () in $team, may I allow these errors to pass the preg_match ?.

There could be other situations like $team2 could be...

```
$team2="U23 Benfica:Vitoria Guimaraes";
$team2="Benfica (U23):Vitoria Guimaraes U23";
$team2="Benfica U23:Vitoria Guimaraes(U23)";
```

and so on ..various situations, this is only an example. All these should match with $team , what can I do to execute this approximate string matching in php  ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should remove `()` from strings and just compare them?

Comment: This is probably what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching. Regex is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: u_mulder , it's not a solution I could have exactly the countrary ..  $team2="Benfica(U23):Vitoria Guimaraes(U23)";  and $team="Benfica U23:Vitoria Guimaraes U23";

Comment: yes I'm asking exactly if an "Approximate string matching" in php is possible, and how ?

Comment: It's not possible if you're looking for a native PHP function. It *is* possible tho to create a function with an algorithm to do what you're looking for, you can try creating it

Comment: You could check out the [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function.

Comment: Magnus, excellent solution for me thank you.

Comment: @gr68 you picked the only answer that does not work. That was very unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to use array_intersect on a multiexploded array.

Remove the `()` and replace with space.
Explode on space and colon and filter out all empty.

Use array_intersect to see how many equal items there is and see if that matches the count of unique items.

This can of course be calibrated by if the count is within a margin if you want that.

```
$team1="U23 Benfica:Vitoria Guimaraes";
$team2="Benfica (U23):Vitoria Guimaraes U23";
var_dump(match($team1, $team2));

$team1="U23 Benfica:Vitoria Guimaraes";
$team2="Benfica U23:Vitoria Guimaraes(U23)";
var_dump(match($team1, $team2));

$team1="Benfica U23:Vitoria Guimaraes(U23)";
$team2="Benfica (U23):Vitoria Guimaraes U23";
var_dump(match($team1, $team2));

function match($s1, $s2){
    // remove the ( and ) and replace with space
    $s1 = str_replace(["(",")"], " ", $s1); 
    $s2 = str_replace(["(",")"], " ", $s2);

    $delimiters = [" ", ":"]; // add more delimiters if needed
    // explode on $delimiters and remove empty values
    $arr1 = array_filter(multiexplode($delimiters,$s1)); 
    $arr2 = array_filter(multiexplode($delimiters,$s2));
//var_dump($arr1, $arr2);

    // How many items is equal between $arr1 and $arr2
    $intersect = count(array_unique(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)));

    // is the count of equal items the same as the count of items in the strings
    if($intersect == count(array_unique($arr1)) && $intersect == count(array_unique($arr2))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

// From PHP manual explode
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}
```

Returns:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

https://3v4l.org/MY7j7

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I deleted this answer having seen the comment about using similar_text, but my experiments on the test strings only gave 78% between team1 and team2. This may be good enough, but I thought an alternative might be useful.

It's worth noting that unless you start using all sorts of pseudo-AI stuff, you're never going to get anything like human recognition. From the looks of things, you are 'sure' that each word will at least be spelt the same. I would suggest splitting the string by any non-alphanumeric character into an array, then sorting the array, and checking it matches a 'master' for each team.

It would look something like (this is untested - the $pattern may need more work)

```
<?php
  $teamString = "Benfica (U23):Vitoria Guimaraes U23";
  $masterArray = ['Benfica','Guimares','U23','Vitoria'];
  $pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z\d]/';
  $teamArray = preg_split( $pattern, $teamString );
  sort($teamArray);
  $interArray = array_unique($teamArray); //to remove duplicate U23
  $finalArray = array_filter($interArray, function($k) {
    return (preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $k) != ''); //to get rid of whitespace
  });
  //...compare $finalArray with $masterArray
```

Of course you can then add logic to solve other problems as you find them...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `levenshtein($team, $team2)` to have a number that represents how much the strings are different, and then define a threshold value to decide how much you want to be tolerant.

```
if (levenshtein($team, $team2) < 3) {
    echo "string are similar";
} else {
    echo "string are not similar";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: That won't work in this case since the strings are not the same. The words are not in the same order thus it will give a very high score. See here: https://3v4l.org/dpHFj